# Paint Event of Viewport3D

Tags: c#, wpf, render, paint

How can I change the rendering of my Viewport3D?  Is there a Paint Event like in winforms?

I want to draw some content in screen space (On the viewport) and not in world space (in the viewport).  Why? Because it's too heavy to draw text and lines directly in viewport3D. I have hundreds of thousands of lines and text to draw. And even if I use good libraries, it slowes the drawing process and inflates the memory dramatically.

Also, I want to draw a rectangle on the surface of viewport3D regardless of the content. (e.g I don't want to calculate where I should draw the rectangle so that it's not behing the objects.)

So drawing on the surface of the viewport3D will be an excellent solution if only I knew how to do it.

Comment: you can override OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) method.

Comment: And that's all ? Ohhh, ok, I'm goind to try this now.

Comment: I have put it as answer. Pls mark and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the OnRender method of the Viewport3D. Refer below code.

```
 class MyViewPort : Viewport3D
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote up requires 15 in reputation... Sorry :s Or.. Upvote my question and I could upvote your response :)

Comment: You can mark as answer by clicking on the tick mark.

Comment: The big problem is that if I want the objects drawn in screen place to move with the camera, I must Invalidate the Viewport when the camera change. So it uses twice the GPU. mmmm